# MySQL 5.7 not configured yet

Tags: mysql, linux, installation, mysql-5.7

I have a personal webserver which were running under Ubuntu 14 LTS and I migrated it under 16.04 LTS a while ago.

Since I did it I have an error with MySQL server every time I'm updating packages on this server. I tried to solve the problem many time, then gave up because my MySQL server is still working but now I'm really bothered about that issue and want to find a fix.

So every time I run `apt-get upgrade` I get :

```
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
```

So I tried everything in that [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760724/16-04-upgrade-broke-mysql-server), removing all the *my.cnf* files and then finally remove the entire mysql folder and try reinstall the MySQL server --> Still get the error.

So I tried as described to get a verbose mode when running configure :

```
+ existingdatabase=1
+ touch /var/lib/mysql/debian-5.7.flag
+ '[' configure = configure ']'
+ APP_PROFILE=/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld
+ '[' -f /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld ']'
+ LOCAL_APP_PROFILE=/etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.mysqld
+ test -e /etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.mysqld
+ aa-status --enabled
+ apparmor_parser -r -T -W /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld
+ deb-systemd-helper unmask mysql.service
+ deb-systemd-helper --quiet was-enabled mysql.service
+ deb-systemd-helper enable mysql.service
+ '[' configure = configure ']'
+ '[' -x /etc/init.d/mysql ']'
+ update-rc.d mysql defaults 19 21
+ '[' -x /etc/init.d/mysql ']'
+ invoke-rc.d mysql start
+ '[' configure = configure ']'
+ '[' 1 = 1 ']'
+ test_sysmaint_access
+ mysql --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf
+ result=0
+ mysql_upgrade --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf
Error occurred: Cannot setup server variables.
+ result=1
+ '[' 1 -ne 0 -a 1 -ne 2 ']'
+ echo 'mysql_upgrade failed with exit status 1'
mysql_upgrade failed with exit status 1
+ exit 1
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Here is just the end of the result but error seems to come from

```
+ mysql_upgrade --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf
Error occurred: Cannot setup server variables.
```

Also I tried to stop *mysqld* and restart it skipping databases:

```
sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables &
```

and run:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Same error. Now I'm out of ideas and if somebody an help me I will be really grateful.

Comment: What version are you upgrading from?  To?

Comment: So, the current version is :  5.7.19-0ubuntu0.16.04.1. So it should be an upgrade from 5.7.19 to 5.7.**.